# Check whether ec2 instance is running or terminated using java aws sdk

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How can we check whether the instance is running or terminated? As terminated instance id remains in the system for some time, but I want to exclude those terminated instances from my running instances list as soon as the instance is terminated. Can someone please guide me how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of terminated or stoped instances, I just put on a check like this

```
 if(reservation.getInstances().getPublicIpAddress()!= null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call following instruction to do so.

```
List<Reservation> reservList = ec2.describeInstances().getReservations(); 

//iterate on reservList and call 

List<Instance> instanceList =  reservList[i].getInstances();

//Now on each instance you can call 

 instanceList[i].getState().getName();
```

This will return the state of each of your instance